# Java request taking 40-50MB memory(Spring JPA Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using spring boot with JPA Hibernate.
I am monitoring the service for Heap and found that each of my request is taking around 40-50 MB.

So the memory gets increased, after few requests GC runs, it frees the memory and this goes on forever.

So my first question is that is this memory leak?

Also I am trying to find what is causing this. So, I have used Runtime.getRuntime() freeMemory and totalMemory() to identify that around 15MB is getting used when getting one db call and populating projection with it

```
public interface RecommendationProjection {
    public String getType();
    public boolean getIsOK();
    public int getId();
    public int getTagCount();
    public double getQuality() ;
    public LocalDateTime getLastActivity();

}
```

and hibernate returns 567 records, so basically what I am getting from DB is list of 567 above projection, But what i dont understand that how could this object take such high memory? Is hibernate causing this?

When using projection, hibernate queries for specific field or fetches all fields from database?

Then I am mapping this domain to DTO, which again uses 15-20MB memory?
this is my DTO

```
public class RecommendationInfoDTO {
    private String type;
    private boolean isOK;
    private int id;
    private int tagCount;
    private double quality ;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone="IST")
    private LocalDateTime lastActivity;


    .. getters and setters
}
```

FYI : For monitoring I am using VisualVM.
Can anybody tell me what is possible issue?

I have also analyzed heap dump but could not get anything?

[image]

This is my heap dump diff.

I am firing 6 hibernate queries in a request and 3 simple plain mysql queries(using jdbc call)

Issue is just 1 hibernate call. I think some thing is wrong with my hibernate ? 
Is there any way I could do request based profiling?

Gc / Memory Graph

[image]

Heap dump sorted on size

[image]

Comment: Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: Can you please post the way you fetch the data (any repository classes, custom queries etc.)? First thing you should do is find out if your projections are working correctly. Log your hibernate generated statements and see if all columns are selected or only projection declared columns are selected.

Comment: Can you show the heap dump that is sorted based on the last column i.e., size?

Comment: What is the min and max heap sizes you are using? How long you have run your app and how many requests you have issued to your app? Are you getting any OOM errors? And can you also show you GC graph.

Comment: I am using Java 8, I have already seen the query projection is working fine. Query is fetching only specific recoreds. Min Heap 512M & Max Heap 1024M. I am testing it on local. So single(without any concurrent request using 40MB)

Comment: Can you run the query couple of times and share your heap memory observations. You can ignore the initial one/two runs and consider the subsequent ones for this observation. And do share your GC graph from visualVM.

Comment: Yes, same even after 10 times. It is consuming 40MB per request

Comment: Okie..would like to see your GC graph from visualVM and the above class instances count that is sorted based on the last column i.e., size.

Comment: updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: That looks like a massively excessive amount of `ConnectionPropertiesImpl` inner class instances given the number of connections to the database. It kind of seems like the problem is in the SQL driver. Try the MariaDB driver (a fork of MySQL, driver is compatible) https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j and tell us if it makes a difference.

Comment: At this point, the question needs to be closed. This already slipped through as a multiple-question question. 

Q1:"Is this a memory leak" A: "No, by definition"

Q2:"Am i using hibernate wrong/is this a bug" etc A:"we cant know what without seeing your code"

Q3:"hibernate queries for specific field or fetches all fields from database?" A: "specific"

Question 2 needs to be opened as a new question, separately.

Comment: I still havent got the answer

Answer (score 8):

This looks to me to be normal behavior.

> So my first question is that is this memory leak?

No. Memory leaks require for the memory to remain allocated beyond its useful life. Since your GC is clearing the total memory space consumed by the query, you are not leaking, you're simply using memory.

> But what i dont understand that how could this object take such high memory?

The object isn't taking much memory, it's the 567 *instances* of the object *per query* that are taking the memory.

Lets take a look to explain why:

Each instance of your projection contains

- a `String` of unknown length (Strings are not primitives, so there are a significant number of metadata attributes one top of the pure character count, but lets just say 1 byte)
- a `boolean` which allocates 1 byte
- 2 `int` of a byte each
- a `double` of 2 bytes
- and `LocalDateTime` which is made of several fields (so lets be optimistic and say at 2 bytes)

So each instance is *at least* 8 bytes.
567 * 8 = 4536 bytes minimum per query.

You're firing 6 queries against this dataset
4536 * 6 = 27216 bytes per method call

Some of this is overhead in hibernate which gets reused between calls, so you won't quite see the full theoretical footprint.

This is relatively close to what you're observing, so I don't think anything is misbehaving.

If you're expecting a smaller footprint, reevaluate your approach to reuse as much data as possible to reduce the number of queries you have to make.

Comment: I am using total 6 queries. But only query is getting executed which is fetching 567 rows. Rest queries are  simple queries and not taking much memory as I have removed all other and still almost same memory is getting used. So its just one query which results in 567 rows.  I am using projection to fetch 6 specific columns? So does hibernate will be using first level cache in this case? If yes, what does it cache. The only issue here I feels is that hibernate / spring data jpa is doing smthng behind the scenes. My query is join query with 3 tables join and fetching 6 columns using projection

Comment: Everything takes memory. There are a ton of things you could be doing wrong. You could be opening transactions without closing them, you could be pooling connections, you could be caching. All we can really tell you is that if the GC is collecting it all, then its not a leak. Anything further needs to be asked as its own question. Stacking multiple questions together usually results in a "Too Broad" Close Vote.

Answer (score 5):

Below is my view:

> So the memory gets increased, after few requests GC runs, it frees the memory and this goes on forever.
>
> So my first question is that is this memory leak?

Not necessarily a memory leak. But you need to run and hit the application for a longer period of time and see how the memory is getting released during GC cycles. As long as the memory usage [kind of follows a sawtooth pattern](https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/memory-leaks-fallacies-and-misconceptions) it is a one indicator that the GC is able to reclaim the garbage and memory is utilized efficiently.

> When using projection, hibernate queries for specific field or fetches all fields from database?

No it fetches only the specified columns in case of projection.

> Then I am mapping this domain to DTO, which again uses 15-20MB memory?

It is not only your DTOs, but `hibernate` and on top of `spring-data-jpa` would be creating their own objects internally to fulfill the query and those objects might be awaiting GC. As long as they are getting reclaimed after GC cycle and the memory usage is not increasing constantly after each GC, it is a healthy sign.

But more than the memory used by each request, you may want to look at the bigger picture and some of the items (**not an exhaustive/complete list**) could be:

1. See how the memory usage is over a period of time for the normal load and peak load scenarios.
2. How frequently are minor and major GC happening and how it impacting the application?
3. Is the application spending too much of time in GC itself"?
4. Tune the GC based on the application behavior. For ex: is the app creating too many short lived objects for serving requests etc.
5. Given the heap/GC configuration, is the application able to meet your application response time and throughput as expected?

And finally you may want to go through [java8 GC tuning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/) to understand the GC and tuning it.